# Why are the rules for the polymorph subschool of magic separated from the rest of the book?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, magic, polymorph, books

When I first bought the core rulebooks for *Dungeons and Dragons* 3.5, I did a cursory look through of all the books. One thing that stuck out to me was the fact that in the very back of the *Player's Handbook*, it showed the rules for the Polymorph Subschool. It struck me as odd for it to be all the way in the back, past all the indices and whatnot, on the very last page.

Why it was done this way? It makes it seem to me that it was an afterthought that they threw in there, but that wouldn't make much sense for a company like Wizards of the Coast to do that. Why wasn't it included at the end of the section on Magic?

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/tour) if you haven't already and see the [help center](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help) if you need more guidance. Good Luck and Happy Gaming!

Comment: To be clear, you have the 2012 printing of the *Player's Handbook*, yes?

Comment: I am pretty sure that is the one, yes. I don't have it with me to verify though.

Answer (score 1):

It was not, originally, a separate subschool. Rather than edit the book itself—which would take a trained typesetter a non-trivial amount of work to make sure nothing got messed up—they just tracked it on to the end of the book in later printings.

Comment: Interesting, so it used to be part of other schools? Or more like an implied school based on the effects of certain spells?

Comment: It may be worth mentioning that in the *Player's Handbook* that section is as misleading as it is superfluous—none of the *PH* spells actually use those rules (*alter self*, the *polymorph*s, and *shapechange* see their specific rules trump those general ones, and even the druid's wild shape now references alternate form from the *Monster Manual*).

Comment: That's kind of odd, thanks for the heads up!

Comment: @Greppo It was an implied thing, those spells were simply Transmutation without subschool.

Comment: Rules Compendium has the final version of the polymorph rules, iirc.